# Elixir: guarding against argument errors

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If I have a pipeline like this:

```
"1" |> String.to_integer
```

How can I guard against it if the string is empty (not nil)?

```
"" |> String.to_integer
** (ArgumentError) argument error
:erlang.binary_to_integer("")
```

Comment: Where do you use this pipeline?

Comment: That's the console there, but it's in a Phoenix module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything depends on the context. For instance you can use default value and use it in your private function.

```
defp convert_to_integer(my_string \\ 0) # if 0 is appropriate default value
  String.to_integer(my_string)
end
```

Of course there's a better way - `Integer.parse`, which returns valid tuple if everything's fine and `:error` if there's something wrong. Just combine it with `cond` or `case`.

```
defp convert_to_integer(my_string)
  result = Integer.parse(my_string)

  case result do
    {number, _} -> number
    :error -> "it didn't work" # or anything      
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that the second snippet will successfully parse an integer followed by anything else e.g. `convert_to_integer("123abc") #=> 123`.

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern matching to guard this:

```
def to_integer(string) when byte_size(string) == 0 do
  # do_something_with_empty_string
  IO.puts "empty"
end

def to_integer(string) do
  # handle your case here
  String.to_integer(string)
end
```

Iex:

```
iex(9)> Test.to_integer("")
empty
:ok
iex(10)> Test.to_integer("2")
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I forget you can overwrite functions in Elixir.

Comment: `to_integer(string) when byte_size(string) == 0` can just be `to_integer("")`.